# Blender 2.83.1 Can't find render bake option in cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texture-baking

I am making a floor texture and want to create a normal map. I looked up some video's and they refer to the Render -> Bake option in cycles. I can't seem to find it. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

Am I doing something wrong or is the option elsewhere?

Comment: What version of blender are you using?

Comment: I don't know where they put it, but I think I found the discussion from when users first started talking about moving it - Some talk about putting it in bake passes, others in object properties, others still, in material settings. Link is here - Maybe you can find a place to look based on the discussion: https://developer.blender.org/D3203

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It took a while before I figured this out. I watched video after video still not knowing how to do it. Until a few days ago I figured it out. I needed to bake a normal map and I still did not have the bake option. Then this popped into my head: "I wonder what happens when I switch it to CPU mode instead of GPU.". After I switched it to CPU I saw the bake option. After about a month I figured it out. They really should add that to the documentation or make it more clear.

TL;DR:

Make sure you use Cycles and use the CPU.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you expand on how you did that, explaining the steps and procedure?

Comment: Well. On all the video's/documentation says to use cycles. So I had to use cycles. Then it just popped in my head that maybe switching to CPU instead of GPU could work and it did.

Comment: Please edit your answer and include additional details into the original post, don't posts them as a comment

Answer (score 0):

Anyone else looking for this solution - figured out I was on OptiX which didn't support baking at the time. Switched back to CUDA and the option was back.